# iOS: Why superview's "layoutsubviews" is not called when view has constraints and is resized?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have two views, view1 and view2, in the current project I am working on. view2 is a subview of view1. I notice if there is NO constraints defined for view2, when I resize view2, view1's "layoutsubviews" is called followed by view2's. However, if I added a constraint to centre view2 within view1, resizing view2 will only trigger view2's "layoutsubviews".

I could not find any documentation to explain this. Is this what's expected? Why the behaviour is different?

Comment: well if you resize view2 (the inside one) it will call `layoutSubviews` of view2 everytime.

Comment: I understand that, but why view1's "layoutsubviews" isn't called when constraint is present? that's what puzzles me.

Comment: it wont be because `view2` is dependent on `view1` as far as i understand, so changing `view2` wont call `layoutsubviews`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is :
 **When we set a constraint to view2, surely will cause view2 itself constraint and frame's change, but if view2 is dependent in view1(which means view2 has no constraint with view1, and view2 has no constraint with other subviews in view1), in this situation, view2 constraint's change will not cause view1's constraint change, and surely will not cause view1's layoutSubviews**